# Powershell Excel SaveAs requires confirmation

Tags: excel, powershell, power-automate, power-platform

I use below script to convert bunch of xls files to xlsx.

```
$folderpath = %tempPath%
$filetype ="*xls"

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
write-host $xlFixedFormat
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include $filetype -recurse | 
ForEach-Object `
{
 $path = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
 
 "Converting $path"
 $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)

 $path += ".xlsx"
 $workbook.saveas($path, $xlFixedFormat)
 $workbook.close()
 

}
$excel.Quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

It used to work perfectly running on VM.
Unfortunately with changing folder path I realised there are popup windows to confirm saving that didn't come up before and the script gets stuck on that.
Any simple corrections that could prevent that error?

```
"scriptError": {
    "localizedName": "Error",
    "value": "Unable to get the SaveAs property of the Workbook class\r\nAt C:\\Users\\~
    "variableName": "ScriptError"
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any pop-up windows, you aren't actually changing the path, just the file extension. What does the pop-up say? The SaveAs method shouldn't prompt to confirm saving.

Comment: This could happen when saving to OneDrive or in Office 365. The Close method can prompt even though the workbook has been already saved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I set the path when saving an Excel file using PowerShell. I set the path using a combination of the **Get-Location** cmdlet, **Get-Date** cmdlet and the file name, which is stored in a string variable for use when saving the script.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$htFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlHtml

$Date = get-date -format R
$CurrentLocation = Get-Location
$CurrentDir = Get-location

$Timestamp = get-date -format d

$xlsx = [String] $CurrentLocation + "\MyNewExcelStuff-" + $Timestamp + ".xlsx"

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.add()
$sheet1 = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet1.name = "Stuff"

$Sheet1.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Reporting Stack Stuff"
$title = $Sheet1.Range("A1:K1")
$title.Select() 
$title.MergeCells = $true
$title.VerticalAlignment = -4108           # Centre (vertically) heading
$title.HorizontalAlignment = -4108         # Centre (horizontally) heading
$Title.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($xlsx, $xlFixedFormat)
Start-Sleep -s 2
$Excel.Quit()
$Excel = $Null
```

Answer (score 1):

try $workbook.SaveCopyAs($path)

I had the same error message in a Powershell script in a azure devops pipeline when i upgraded to office 2016. it was working with office 2010.

after the upgrade it stoped working but The script was still working fine manually on the same upgraded build machine.

1. I tried SaveCopyAs eventually.
2. I also added the following lines to my code

   $excel.visible = $false

   $excel.DisplayAlerts=$false
3. I also created the following folders:

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should use `$workbook.Close($false)`.